# How to display JSON use vanilla js on laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, typescript

I'm new in laravel, and i want to pass JSON data from my controller use vanilla js to my view blade but I didn't know how to use it

here's my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('cari'))
    {
        $data_siswa = \App\Siswa::where('nama','LIKE','%'.$request->cari.'%')->get();
    }
    else
    {
        $data_siswa = \App\Siswa::all();
    }



    return response()->json(array('data_siswa' => $data_siswa));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for ajax, just echo the json to the page as a javascript variable

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('cari'))
    {
        $data_siswa = \App\Siswa::where('nama','LIKE','%'.$request->cari.'%')->get();
    }
    else
    {
        $data_siswa = \App\Siswa::all();
    }
     $data_siswa = $data_siswa->toJson();


    return view('index',compact('data_siswa'));
}
```

in your view you simply do

```
<script>
var data_siswa = {{$data_siswa}};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be easiest as an ajax request. As far as doing it with vanilla js you could use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
const response = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json');
const myJson = await response.json();
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

In your case you'd be able to access the `data_siswa` array with `myJson.data_siswa`